# Is there a better way to solve this problem? A question from the 24th PMO

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math

For context, this contest was held today. And for transparency, I was one of the participants. This is Problem 16 from the [24th Philippine Mathematical Olympiad](https://www.facebook.com/PhilippineMathematicalOlympiad/posts/5133045126757413). :

> What is the largest multiple of $7$ less than $10000$ which can be represented as the sum of squares of three consecutive numbers?

I got the correct answer, which is $8750$.

---

We can let the sum of the squares of the three consecutive numbers as \begin{align*}S &= (a - 1)^2 + a^2 + (a + 1)^2\\ S &= a^2 - 2a + 1 + a^2 + a^2 + 2a + 1 \\ S &= 3a^2 + 2\end{align*} Here, $a$ is the middle number.

Clearly, the lower bound of $a$ is $14$ since the second smallest integer is $2$, and $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 14$. Solving for the upper bound,
\begin{align*}
3a^2 + 2 &\leq 10000 \\
3a^2 &\leq 9998 \\
a^2 &\leq 3332.\bar{6}
\end{align*}

By trial-and-error, the greatest square less than or equal to $3332.\bar{6}$ is $57^2$. Hence, $2 \leq a \leq 57$.

From the statement, we must have
\begin{align*}
(3a^2 + 2) &\equiv 0 \bmod 7 \\
3a^2 &\equiv 5 \bmod 7 \\
a^2 &\equiv 4 \bmod 7
\end{align*}

Evaluating $i^2$ for $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 6\}$, we can see that the applicable values are $\{2, 5\}$. Hence, the value of $a^2$ must be a multiple of $2$ or $5$, but not both. Luckily, the last numbers are multiples of $2$ or $5$, and trying the last three, we have
\begin{align*}
56^2 &\equiv 0 \bmod 7 \\
55^2 &\equiv 1 \bmod 7 \\
54^2 &\equiv 4 \bmod 7
\end{align*}

This means that what we are looking for is $a = 54$. Solving for $S$,
\begin{align*}
S &= 3a^2 + 2 \\
S &= 3\cdot 54^2 + 2 \\
S &= 3 \cdot 2916 + 2 \\
S &= 8748 + 2 \\
S &= 8750
\end{align*}

Therefore, the largest multiple of $7$ less than $10000$ which can be represented as the sum of squares of three consecutive numbers is $8750$.

---

Can I ask how to shorten this proof, if this can be shorted?

Edit(s):

1. The expression $a$ is replaced with $a^2$ in this part:

> Hence, the value of $a$ must be a multiple of $2$ or $5$, but not both.

which becomes

> Hence, the value of $a^2$ must be a multiple of $2$ or $5$, but not both.

Comment: It's not that $a$ must be a multiple of $2$ or $5$, as you claim, but rather that $a$ must be $\equiv \pm 2\pmod 7$.  Very different.

Comment: @lulu How different is it? I get that $5 \equiv -2 \bmod 7$, but I don't get how that's different.

Comment: To avoid trivial editing, it should be "For context", not "For contest".

Comment: The multiples of $2$ are just the even numbers, so $\{2,4,6,8,\cdots\}$.  Most of those do not work.  $4$, for instance, does not work.

Comment: Note, your mistake doesn't end up leading you to an incorrect result because you ignore the solution for $a$ entirely.  Instead you just use $a^2\equiv 4\pmod 7$ which lets you skip over your error.  But you need to persuade yourself that your solution for $a$ is incorrect.

Comment: @lulu Oh, right. I forgot that $a^2 = 4$ implies $a = \pm 2$ which leads to my conclusion that $a$ must be a multiple of $2$ and $5$. But either way, this part was skipped by the trial-and-error.

Comment: No, the error was skipped because you applied the trial and error to $a^2$, not to $a$.  Had you applied your mistake you would have noted that $56$ is a multiple of $2$, so you would have stopped there.

Comment: Worth noting:  given that you are just planning on using trial and error anyway, I'd skip all the modular arithmetic.  It takes time and you scarcely even use it.  Just test each case of $3a^2+2$ to find one divisible by $7$ with $a$ as close to $57$ as possible.

Comment: @lulu If trial-and-error is not allowed, how can this be solved?

Comment: In that case, I would use modular arithmetic.  If you had solved for $a$ correctly, you'd know to look for numbers of the form $7n+2$ and $7n+5$ which are $≤57$.  Taking $56$ as the multiple of $7$ yields no solutions (as $56+2>57$) so you must use $49$.  We then are led to consider $a=49+2=51$ or $a=49+5=54$.  Clearly $54$ is the larger and as it is still in range, that's the answer.

Comment: @lulu I think your answer is enough. If it's okay, may I ask if you can post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The OP's solution contains an error which doesn't impact the final result.  Specifically, the solution for $a$ ought to be $a\equiv \pm 2 \pmod 7$, not "multiples of $2$ or $5$".  This doesn't matter in the end, because the OP only ends up looking at $a^2$ anyway, so never uses the incorrect computation of $a$.

For a shorter argument which avoids serious trial and error:  Use the fact that $a≤57$.  Then, using the correct solution, $a\equiv \pm 2\pmod 7$ we see that we are looking for the largest number $≤57$ which has the form $7n+2$ or $7n-2$.  Inspection shows that $56-2=54$ is the largest such, and we are done.